# Object attributes and dictionaries

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, dictionary

Compare

```
class Results(object):
    foo = 1
    bar = 1
r = Results()
r.__dict__ 
Out[54]: {}
```

and

```
class Results(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 1
        self.bar = 1
r = Results()
r.__dict__
Out[57]: {'foo': 1, 'bar': 1}
```

I'm used to do the first case for short classes with mostly hold attributes, for its shorter logic. `r.foo` will work in both cases, but apparently the dictionary getter will not.

Could someone shortly explain the difference in setting up the class in the two ways? Is there a simple way to reconcile the first type of classes such that `.__dict__` will actually show all of the attributes?

Comment: Why do you want to use `__dict__` in the first place?

Comment: I would like to save object properties in a `pandas` data frame.

Comment: I'd use `vars()` instead of `__dict__`, but that also only returns the instance dictionary. The next option is a loop over `dir()` and then accessing attributes with `getattr()`.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is in the first case, the members are of the class, while in the second case, they are members of the object. In the first case, you can do `Results.__dict__` to see that this is the case.